# Asking much sauce in bottle

Tags: word-choice

A small boy ask his mom to pour so much sauce in the bottle:

> "Mom, please pour all of the sauce on the pizza."
>
> "Mom, please pour the sauce on the pizza a lot."

What would a native English speaker choose or say in this situation?

Comment: As an Italian I protest at the idea of someone pouring sauce (tomato ketchup?) on my beloved pizzas! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - based on the context, I'm guessing that they are [preparing the pizza](http://www.budgetbytes.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Pizza-Sauce-angle.jpg). Yum. :^)

Comment: But @J.R. sauce from a bottle? I still protest! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Things could be worse. [A lot worse](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-kcBxJ5O97e4/TZTrsx8FrWI/AAAAAAAADr8/9jRv7gMslYg/s1600/totinos_pepperoni_party_pizza_01.JPG).

Comment: Three different types of meat... meat... sorry. I am speechless.

Comment: alright mari :) no one beats italian when it comes to pizza :) (i'm honoring that) , by the way thanks for the answer guys. Now i get the clear idea to use a lot , and all when i want to buy pizzas Yum :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much "so much" is.

If the container will be empty at the end, then your first sentence is just fine:

> "Please pour **all (of) the sauce** on the pizza."

The preposition is optional. In this context, *all the sauce* and *all of the sauce* mean the same thing.

However, if the boy is just asking for "a lot of sauce" (but not the entire contents of the jar or bottle):

> Please pour **a lot of sauce** on the pizza.

If this conversation was between me and my local pizzaria, instead of a boy and his mom, I might use less formal terminology:

> Please **go heavy on the sauce**.

which is a request to use more sauce than usual. Another way to make the same request would be:

> Can I have **extra sauce**, please?

Comment: Itza pizzeria! :-)

Comment: @Mari-Lou - I cannot bring myself to fix my spelling error, because it would render your comment obsolete.

Comment: +1 But I don't know too many natives that would use *pour*- they'd probably use *put* instead.

Comment: @Jim - Excellent point. I spent so much time mulling over "all of the sauce" that I didn't pay much attention to the verb. One might use _pour_ with something that was more liquid (e.g., _pour some milk in a glass; pour some syrup on the pancake_), but for sauce on pizza – which needs to be spread evenly with a spoon – _put_ would likely be the verb of choice.

Comment: If you fix the spelling, I'll delete my comment. No problemo. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - That's the point! Who would want _"Itza pizzeria!"_ deleted? Not me.